What do angular momenta stretched states look like on vector cone diagrams?
I am trying to understand the Clebsch-Gordan decomposition of hyperfine $|F, m_F \rangle$ states and came across the fact that for stretched states, i.e. where $|m_F|= F$ and $F=|I+J|$, the decomposition simply equates to a single $|m_I, m_J \rangle$ state without any superposition in the uncoupled basis.
Would this imply that for stretched states, both {$m_I, m_J$} and {$F, m_F$} are good quantum numbers? This is confusing for me because I cannot visualize what that would look like on a vector cone diagram (mapping the LS coupling in the image to IJ coupling). From that, it becomes almost intuitive that if the latter are good quantum numbers, then the former cannot be so. This is because the 'base' of the corresponding $\vec I$ and $\vec J$ cones would always be making an angle with the quantization (z) axis. Because of that, since the z projection of $\vec I$
and $\vec J$ would not be constant, it would not be possible to define $m_I$ and $m_J$. The only case where I could imagine that to be possible would be if $\vec F$ were to align completely with the quantization axis, but that is also not possible in quantum mechanics as that would mean that all three components of $\vec F$ are known. So what do such states look like on vector cone diagrams for all of these quantum numbers to be well defined?
Side note: My current understanding of vector cone diagrams is that they are visualization tools for understanding expectation values of operators along the quantization axis, while taking into consideration that components in the plane perpendicular to it should not be interpreted as physical as they cannot be defined simultaneously with z components.

It's not clear what you mean by squeezed states (those have nothing to do with the hyperfine structure).

In the context of atomic physics, I have understood them to mean $|F, m_F\rangle$ states where $m_F$ takes the highest or lowest possible value (i.e., +F or -F, respectively). That is how they are referred to in my research group but I'm not sure how it aligns with the general definition of squeezed states.

Okay, I did some digging, and I see that this does not fit the definition of squeezed states. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Okay I understand my mistake. I had meant stretched states instead of squeezed states.
